# Legion of the Bouncy Castle

Tags: android, blackberry, bouncycastle

How do I use [bouncy castle](http://bouncycastle.org/java.html) encryption and decryption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From their [documentation page](http://bouncycastle.org/documentation.html):

> To view some examples, look at the test programs in the packages:
>
> - org.bouncycastle.crypto.test
> - org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.test
> - org.bouncycastle.cms.test
> - org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.test
> - org.bouncycastle.openpgp.test
> - org.bouncycastle.tsp.test